# Need an overview of debugging process from the hardware layer

Tags: linux, debugging, x86, gdb

I want a comprehensive overview of how the debugging process occurs on a typical  x86 machine running Linux operating system; let's say the program used for debugging is gdb. Question #1 : is the process of debugging facilitated by the hardware (or it is implemented completely in software instead?). If so, what architecture features from the instruction set are involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x86 ISA includes a single-byte [`int3`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) encoding that's intended for software breakpoints.  GDB uses this (via ptrace) by default for breakpoints.

([Why Single Stepping Instruction on X86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941988/why-single-stepping-instruction-on-x86))

x86 also has a Trap Flag (TF) in EFLAGS for single-step mode.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag).  See also [Difference between trap flag (TF) and monitor trap flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725401/difference-between-trap-flag-tf-and-monitor-trap-flag)

There are even "debug registers" for setting *hardware* breakpoints, without modifying the machine code to be run.  And also hardware support for watch points, to break on write to a certain address.  This makes GDB watch points efficient, not requiring it to single-step and manually decode the instruction to see where it writes.

https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86#Debug_Registers

[Implementing hardware breakpoints using x86 debug register](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25540) osdev forum thread might be relevant.

---

Some other ISAs exist without nearly as much HW support for debugging.  e.g. without a single-step flag, a debugger might have to always decode the current instruction (pointed to by program counter) to find the next one to be executed, and set a software breakpoint there.

ARM Linux used to do that to implement `ptrace` single-step, but that disassembler code was removed from the kernel and now just returns `-EIO`.  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=425fc47adb5bb69f76285be77a09a3341a30799e is the commit that removed it.